# How to fix empty table of content in Pylatex?

Tags: python, flask, latex, pylatex

I'm trying to generate a pdf file using pylatex and pdf latex.
I have sections and subsection in my document and I want to create a table of contents like this:

```
doc.append(NewPage())
doc.append(Command('tableofcontents'))
doc.append(NoEscape(r'\clearpage'))
```

but after I compile it it generates a blank page with just

**Contents**

I do not know how can I solve this problem.
And this is mt generate command:

```
doc.generate_pdf(filepath=filepath, compiler=pdflatex_path, clean_tex=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

In plain $\LaTeX$, you need to run a second pass to get the table of contents. The first pass creates an intermediate file with section headers and their page numbers. Since you are passing `clean_tex=True`, probably this file is being deleted before you can run the second pass.

The [documentation](https://jeltef.github.io/PyLaTeX/current/faq.html) says that you can install `latexmk` to do this automatically. PyLaTeX will detect and use this.